# If an "else" clause is missing in a level sensitive block

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, digital-logic

If a block is level sensitive and there is a missing else clause, then what it is going to infer.

Comment: If the if-else statement is a blocking statement and without event control, there is no latch/register inferred. Otherwise, there are two possibilities, first one choice is to infer a latch; second one choice is an asynchronous combination feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a level sensitive block, if you make an assignment to any variable, you must make an assignment to that variable in all possible branches through that block. Otherwise you may infer a latch for that variable. So you really need to analyze that block to see if the missing else clause would cause a missing assignment. For example

```
always_comb
   begin
   A = 0;
   if(B)
      A = C;
   end
```

In this example, there will always be an assignment to A, so no latch inferred. Note that if you use `always_comb`, you should get an error if fail to make an assignment in all possible branches. (There are a few exceptions to this rule that we can save for another day)